# Some vector space clarifications

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to dissipate some doubts about vector spaces. Let us suppose that we have a vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ over some field (finite), say $K$ with $p$ elements. The number of elements is always is $n$ was written in my notes, but I am kind of not convinced. I wonder because $p$ and $n$ are related in some way. Is this correct?

Clarification:

To phrase the question clearly,

> How many vectors does an n-dimensional vector space over a finite
> field with p elements possess?

My initial reaction is that $n$ is related to $p$. But Im not seeing as obvious the fact that $n$ is the answer. Am I missing a piece of enlightment?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question.  It seems clear to me that $n$ is the dimension of the vector space, but $p$ is the cardinality of the base field.  There is no reason at all why the one should be related to the other.

Comment: @Xander I edited the question.

Comment: A vector in an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field with $p$ elements can be represented by an ordered tuple.  How many entries are there in such a tuple?  What are the possible values that each entry could take?

Comment: Ok, say $p=2$, then the elements of the space are $(1,0)$, $(0,1), (0,0)$ or $(1,1)$. So we have 4 elements. My confusion is that $n$ depends on $p$. Once $p$ is specified, then we know what $n$ is. The problem gives $n$ a priori.

Comment: $n$ and $p$ need not have any relation to each other at all.  In your example, both $p$ and $n$ are the same.  What happens if they are different?  If your problem specifies $n$ *a prior*, perhaps you could reproduce the entirety of the given problem here.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66204/620957). And yes, your notes are wrong: the number is $p^n$.